# The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. in WCF error

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I have written my service in framework 4.0 using C#. It's an simple method which returns a value

The Web.config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="0E1F430D6FFFA91FBEDAEC1D2DDAAC2127EB055DBAFB78328C5BDE83249A94EA66400453B" decryptionKey="A13EACEAAABBECF2D06619924A8" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DecryptCookie.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFandEFService/ProductService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""  binding="wsHttpBinding"    contract="DecryptCookie.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract = "IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

When I try to consume the service, I am getting an error like this:

```
Error: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. 
For more information about the error, either turn on
IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from
the configuration behavior) on the server in   order to send the exception
information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace
logs.System.Exception {System.ServiceModel.FaultException}
```

I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I get these cryptic errors, I turn on tracing and create a service log (.svcLog).  You can then load/read this file using the Service Trace Viewer tool.  This will give you detailed data regarding the error(s).  Follow the instructions on this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

Comment: Where are the trace files stored? Where can I configure that location?

Comment: @MikeCaron...You set the location in the .config file.  I think you can create a relative path so you're good when your app changes environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check the Proxy file. check whether have you updated any thing in business/data access file and not updated the proxy. this is due to proxy error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case when you copy project from one system to another.
in this case you must delete the endpoint from the web.config and you should add service reference again.

Try configure tracing to get more error info:

Open the app.config file of WCF service library and add the configuration for system.diagnostics

````
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
            switchValue="Critical,Information,ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
                 <add name="messages"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
          </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding diagnostics your **web.config** file to get logs:

```
 <system.diagnostics> 
      <sources> 
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                switchValue="All" 
                propagateActivity="true"> 
          <listeners> 
            <add name="traceListener" 
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                initializeData= "D:\AppLogs\Traces.svclog" /> 
          </listeners> 
        </source> 
      </sources> 
    </system.diagnostics>
```